# How can I correct the code to read a xml file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

This code works as it is but when I reference an external xml file in doc.Loadxml, it stops working. How can I get it to work? I don't quite understand.

I use this to call GetXmlData and provide source for the gridview :GridView1.ItemsSource = GetXmlData();

```
   private static object GetXmlData()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
        <Products>
          <Product>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>ASP.NET</Name>
          </Product>
        </Products>
         ");

        XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
        provider.IsAsynchronous = false;
        provider.Document = doc;
        provider.XPath = "Products/Product";

        return new ObservableCollection<XmlNode>((IEnumerable<XmlNode>)provider.Data);
    }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the XML you are trying to load is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
  doc.Load(fileName);
```

instead of

```
  doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

`XMLDocument` has several `Load` methods, see [them with their description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx):

```
Load(Stream)      Loads the XML document from the specified stream.
Load(String)      Loads the XML document from the specified URL.
Load(TextReader)  Loads the XML document from the specified TextReader.
Load(XmlReader)   Loads the XML document from the specified XmlReader.
LoadXml(string)   Loads the XML document from the specified string.
```

You're using the last one which is as described used to load XML from a string.

Since you need to load the XML from a file, so you've to use to `Load` method, as opposed to `LoadXml`. I think second method is better suited for your situation. You can pass the fullpath of the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file_path);
```

The method you are calling only loads xml from a string. You need to read it from a file which requires a different method.